# Incompatible Types while adding a button

Tags: java, android, button

I get the Error

'Incompatible types
Required: android.widget.Button
found: android.view.View'

Now there's an error with the class...

They said I shall rename the file, but I have a MapsActivity in my code too

This is my Code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        final Toolbar customToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        customToolbar.setTitle("Hello");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Titeltest");

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        TextView mTitle = (TextView) customToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    }

}
public class ButtonClass extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Insert Action if clicking on button here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast your view to button:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
```

edit:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Insert Action if clicking on button here
            }
        });
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        final Toolbar customToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        customToolbar.setTitle("Hello");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Titeltest");

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        TextView mTitle = (TextView) customToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    }

}
```

Comment: did it. But now a error 'class ButtonClass is public, should be declared in a file named ButtonClass.java ' appears

Comment: you should rename your class file to ButtonClass.java

Comment: @MrHarrison Change your file name to your class name.

Comment: but I have a 'public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback' too

Comment: remove "extends Activity" if you want to use a nested class

Comment: but then 'onCreate' 'setcontentView' and 'findViewById' turns into red

Comment: Now I see your edited codes, you can move your ButtonClass inside the MapsActivity class or create a new class file named as ButtonClass.java and copy your codes there

Comment: the app starts! But I can not see the button

Comment: if you want to use the button inside MapsActivity.class then move the codes inside the ButtonClass to MapsActivity's onCreate method

Comment: also you have to use the RelativeLayout in your xml layout to see your button on top of the map

Comment: checked, but the button doesn't appear

Comment: can you post your activity_maps layout?

Comment: after changing to relative layout, as you said it appears

Comment: OK, Good Luck to you!